# Comparing dates after ISOString conversion

Tags: javascript

I need to compare two dates in my code and to make sure I don't make any mistakes with time zones, I need to handle this comparison in UTC.

My code looks like this:

```
const date1String = "7/15/2017 15:00"; // I get this from backend API. To keep it simple, I showed it as a declaration.
const date1 = new Date(date1String).toISOString();
const dateToTest = new Date(2017, 7, 21, 10, 0).toISOString();

if(date1 < dateToTest) {

   // Some logic here
}
```

The `date1String` is a value I receive from my backend API which comes in string format but is always in UTC so I'm trying to convert it to a JavaScript `date` while keeping it in UTC. The `dateToTest` is a date value I generate within a `for` loop.

I'm getting an `invalid time value` error where my date comparison is.

How do I handle this date comparison?

UPDATE: 
Here's a screen shot of actual code where `disabledDates["disableBefore"]` is the value I'm getting from the API.

[image]

Comment: what browser are you having this issue in? It seems fine in chrome

Comment: I'm using Chrome

Comment: Everything seems fine with the code you gave https://jsfiddle.net/5wo7y73t/1/

Comment: Strange. I posted a screen shot of the error I'm getting.

Comment: Figured it out. It was the format in which the date was coming from the API. When I set it to standard US format, it worked fine. JS is smart enough to know that the date is in US format. Before I was trying to manipulate the string format to make it look more like the JS UTC format.

Comment: looks like disabledDates["disabledBefore"] is in an incorrect format or null

Comment: @DerekLawrence Yes, I noticed that too. See the previous comment I posted. Thank you for pointing it out though.

Comment: Yeah I was in the middle of commenting when you added that. Glad you were able to solve it!